# Cropping single layer crops entire cavas?

Tags: gimp

I don't know what's going with my Gimp, but for some reason when I tried to crop a single layer it cropped the entire canvas. ***I know*** that this is abnormal because I've been using Gimp for about a couple weeks for fashion/outfit design (instead of Polyvore) and I have had no problem with cropping before.

All I do is just drag the rectangle over my image, press enter, and I'm done.  I can position my image next to any pair of shoes I want...  Did I accidentally press something on my keyboard to change the settings?

Answer (score 6):

To crop the current layer rather than the canvas please tick the corresponding option in the crop tool settings tab:

[image]

This is the same behaviour in Gimp 2.8 or 2.10.